# I want to get all Entities from nested JSON Data where the "ai_id" has the Value = 0

Tags: elasticsearch

i have this bellow JSON Data, and i want to write a Query in Elasticsearch , the Query is ,
(Give me all Entities where the "ai_id" has the Value = 0 ).

the JSON Data ist :

```
      {
        "_index": "try1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "target": {
            "br_id": 0,
            "an_id": 0,
            "ai_id": 0,
            "explanation": [
              "element 1",
              "element 2"
            ]
          },
          "process": {
            "an_id": 1311,
            "pa_name": "micha"
          },
          "text": "hello world"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "try1",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "target": {
            "br_id": 0,
            "an_id": 1,
            "ai_id": 1,
            "explanation": [
              "element 3",
              "element 4"
            ]
          },
          "process": {
            "an_id": 1311,
            "pa_name": "luca"
          },
          "text": "the all People are good"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I tried this but seems not to Work , Please any Help i will be thankfull.

```
GET try1\_search   
{
  "query":{
        { "match_all": { "ai_id":   0}}
  }
}
```

and this did not work too,

```
GET try1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "query" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"ai_id" : 0} }
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please an Suggestion .
thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to query nested on your `target` object like this-

```
GET /try1/_search
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "target",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "match" : {"target.ai_id" : 0} }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Ref.** https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

Comment: @sam glad it helps you somehow. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If the answer helps? Vote it up and mark it as an answer by clicking on the gray tick :)